# how get last inserted id in multiple record insert?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a tag system which I want allow users to insert multiple tag in a text input. And then I want insert each tag in `tag_table` and need their id for keep in `tag_post_table`.

I know that in multiple insert `last_insert_id` return the first record id. Co can I add count of tags to `last_insert_id` for getting the real last id and use every id between them? Is this reliable?

I read this article, but I don't understand it completely

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: You can only get the insert id of the 1-st row. It might be possible to  make sure the ids are consecutive by using `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` option (and possibly other settings), but I haven't tried it and it will be difficult to test properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637367/mysql-last-insert-id-used-with-multiple-records-insert-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand [this article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

> With `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` set to 0 (“traditional”) or 1 (“consecutive”), the auto-increment values generated by any given statement will be consecutive, without gaps, because the table-level AUTO-INC lock is held until the end of the statement, and only one such statement can execute at a time.

Setting `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` to 0 or 1 guarantees that the auto incemented ids are consecutive.

So the ID you get from `LAST_INSERT_ID` is the first of the new IDs and `LAST_INSERT_ID` + "the number of affected rows" is the last of the new IDs.

Also [`LAST_INSTERT_ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is not affected by other connections

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

But notice, that there may be wrong results, if you use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `INSERT IGNORE ...`. But I have not tested this.