# How to get multiple LAST_INSERT_ID() via stored procedure in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, stored-procedures

I have implement the SELECT multiple records and INSERT to another table in a stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `publish`(IN `userid` MEDIUMINT)
    NO SQL
BEGIN

INSERT INTO `master_live`
(
    `Title`                  
)                      

   SELECT 
    `Title`
 FROM `breakingnewsmaster` WHERE user_id= userid;

END
```

How to get the multiple LAST_INSERT_ID() in stored procedure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't get multiple insert IDs. You can get only **one** generated by the **last insert query**.

Comment: Thanks, I unable to get the multiple insert IDs in store procedure.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637367/mysql-last-insert-id-used-with-multiple-records-insert-statement . Short answer is, you can't.